# How do I configure an Azure App Service setting that isn't in the <appSettings> section of the web.config?

Tags: azure, web-config, azure-web-app-service, raygun

I'm using deployment slots in an Azure App Service and overriding several web.config values by using Application Settings in each slot.

I have a setting for Raygun, an error tracking service that is in a special section of the web.config. The Raygun key is stored in a `<RaygunSettings>` section.

The Azure section for **Application settings** corresponds to key-value pairs in the `<appSettings>` section.

Connection strings correspond to named connection strings in the `<connectionStrings>` section.

Here is a screen shot of a web.config file that illustrates the issue I'm trying to resolve:

[image: Web.config with RaygunSettings section]

How can I override the RaygunSettings section in the Azure App Service Application Settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible from within the Azure app settings page. 
See: [How to override web.config values in custom section in Azure Web App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40300716/how-to-override-web-config-values-in-custom-section-in-azure-web-app)

An alternative would be to set this in your deployment pipeline. 
For example: This can be done using a variable in the release stage, if you use Azure Dev Ops.

Other pipelines will have their own methods too.

Comment: I was afraid this would be the answer. It would be so nice if we could do this using Azure app settings.

Comment: Are you using a deployment pipeline?

Comment: We are. I'll take a look at that approach. Thanks for your help.